# Android SharedPreference not being stored

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm experiencing an issue when retrieving a "just stored" preference.
Here's the simplified scenario and relevant code

Fragment #1

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mPreferences = getActivity()
        .getApplicationContext()
        .getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ...
}


private void someAction(String value){
    mPreferences
        .edit()
        .putString(MY_KEY, value)
        .commit();

    mBus.sendEvent( someEvent ); // -->
}
```

Fragment #2

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mPreferences = getActivity()
        .getApplicationContext()
        .getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    mBus.register(this);
    ...
}

private void onSomeEvent( SomeEvent event ){
    String value = mPreferences.getString( MY_KEY, null );

    // ///////
    // value is null !!! whats going on?
}
```

1) Both fragments are added to the activity on the `Activity.onCreate` method and the fragments

2) Fragment #1 stores a SharedPreference and sends an bus event to Fragment #2

3) Fragment #2 catches the bus event, and retrieves the same preference stored on 2)

4) Preference value is null, preference is not stored on /data/data//shared_preferences/pref-filename.xml

Note: can not send `value` on the bus event, it has to go through a `SharedPreference` for other reasons.

What am I missing? 
Why isn't the preference available right after saving it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the commit to SharedPrefs has been successful?

Comment: Well, other preferences are being stored correctly. I have tried using commit() and apply() and neither worked. I will check the result of the commit operation just in case.

Comment: Make sure `PREF_FILENAME` is same.

Comment: Why cant you send the value you need in the other fragment in the "SomeEvent" Object? You're obviously using EventBus or something very similar, and in EventBus at least, you can post your own custom Events.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking at an old version of shared preferences, try this solution:

```
private void onSomeEvent( SomeEvent event ) {
    mPreferences = getActivity() .getApplicationContext()     .getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String value = mPreferences.getString( MY_KEY, null );
}
```

Comment: That would not matter. SharedPreferance fetches whatever current status of any value is there. Objects life does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to apply a breakpoint just after committing the value. When debugger reaches there, go to evaluate expression button and type mPreference. It will display the info about object. There you can see whether there is value saved in it or not.

Do the same thing before accessing the value in Fragment2 as well. See value is there or not. If value is not there or changed to null, some code is changing value in between for sure.

If this does not solve your problem either, try integrating with [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) Excellent tool by facebook team to analyse your DB and sharedpreference (and many more things).